# Tkinter remove stored file from memory

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

```
    from Tkinter import *
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk
    import tkFileDialog
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure

    class Look():
        def __init__(self, master):
            self.master = master
            self.master.title("Demo")
            self.master.configure(background = "grey91") #the color will be changed later
            self.master.minsize(500, 300) # width + height
            self.master.resizable(False, False)

            self.top_frame = ttk.Frame(self.master, padding = (10, 10))
            self.top_frame.pack()

            ttk.Button(self.top_frame, text = "Load file", command = self.load_file,
               style = "TButton").pack()

            ttk.Button(self.top_frame, text = "Reset", command = self.clear_file,
                   style = "TButton").pack()

            ttk.Button(self.top_frame, text = "Plot", command = self.plot_file,
                              style = "TButton").pack()

            self.bottom_frame = ttk.Frame(self.master, padding = (10, 10))
            self.bottom_frame.pack()

            self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5), dpi=100) ##create a figure; modify the size here
            self.fig.add_subplot()

            plt.title("blah")

            self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master = self.bottom_frame)
            self.canvas.show()
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, self.bottom_frame)
            self.toolbar.update()
            self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        def load_file(self):
            self.file =  tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(defaultextension = ".txt", filetypes = [("Text Documents", "*.txt")])

        def clear_file(self):
            self.fig.clf()
            self.fig.add_subplot()

            plt.xticks()
            plt.yticks()

            self.canvas.draw()


        def plot_file(self):
            self.r, self.g = np.loadtxt(self.file).transpose()
            self.fig.clf()
            plt.plot(self.r, self.g)
            self.canvas.show()


    def main():
        root = Tk()
        GUI = Look(root)
        root.mainloop()

    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

The code above creates a program has three buttons. The Load file buttom loads a txt file, Reset button is supposed to clear the plot and delete the file just loaded into the memory. Plot button is to plot the figure onto canvas below.

I have a question about how to write function associated with Reset function, i.e. clear_file function. Currently what it does is just clear the plot from canvas. But it seems the file that has been loaded to plot is stored in memory, since click again Plot, it will display the plot. My goal is to use Reset button to bring it to a fresh start--nothing stored in memory. I know loading a new file will overwrite the previous file. But when there are multiple buttons for loading different files, the situations could become complicated. Therefore I hope Reset can do the job.
If you want to try this little program, you may create a simple txt with two column data to be loaded into the program.

Thanks.

Comment: Do not import tkinter twice. Remove the line `from Tkinter import *` and just use `import Tkinter as tk`. There is no reason do import tkinter twice. That said you could store your plot as a class attribute and then destroy said attribute with the reset button. Also if you put everything in a frame and destroy the frame it will destroy all the content inside that frame. Then you can simple remake everything.

Comment: Thank you. This sounds very useful. Could you provide a snippet of code for implementing this, for this toy sample?

Answer (score 1):

I would make 2 changes. Move the code that sets up your plot into its own method and reset the frame each time the method is called. This can be done with destroying the frame and remaking it. The 2nd change I would change the command on your reset to reference this new method.

Taking your code this is what I would change to be able to reset the plot.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class Look():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Demo")
        self.master.configure(background = "grey91") #the color will be changed later
        self.master.minsize(500, 300) # width + height
        self.master.resizable(False, False)

        self.top_frame = ttk.Frame(self.master, padding = (10, 10))
        self.top_frame.pack()

        ttk.Button(self.top_frame, text = "Load file", command = self.load_file,style = "TButton").pack()
        ttk.Button(self.top_frame, text = "Reset", command = self.new_plot,style = "TButton").pack()
        ttk.Button(self.top_frame, text = "Plot", command = self.plot_file,style = "TButton").pack()

        self.bottom_frame = ttk.Frame(self.master, padding = (10, 10))
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

        self.new_plot()

    # this function will reset your plot with a fresh one.
    def new_plot(self):
        self.bottom_frame.destroy()
        self.bottom_frame = ttk.Frame(self.master, padding = (10, 10))
        self.bottom_frame.pack()
        self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5), dpi=100) ##create a figure; modify the size here
        self.fig.add_subplot()
        plt.title("blah")
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master = self.bottom_frame)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas, self.bottom_frame)
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    def load_file(self):
        self.file =  filedialog.askopenfilename(defaultextension = ".txt", filetypes = [("Text Documents", "*.txt")])

    def clear_file(self):
        self.fig.clf()
        self.fig.add_subplot()

        plt.xticks()
        plt.yticks()

        self.canvas.draw()


    def plot_file(self):
        self.r, self.g = np.loadtxt(self.file).transpose()
        self.fig.clf()
        plt.plot(self.r, self.g)
        self.canvas.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    GUI = Look(root)
    root.mainloop()
```